# Cannot find Additional Behaviours parameters in JJB

Tags: jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to create my jobs through JJB and almost all parameters are present.
But I can't find the parameters for the repositories that are in the Additional Behaviours category.
Tell me how to configure them using JJB?
Maybe you need additional plugins?[Options screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWrCm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The list of options in the web UI are for the git plugin. You can find them in JJB under the `git` `scm` module. If you wanted to add `Prune stale remote-tracking branches (`git remote prune origin`) you would use:

```
- job:
  name: git-prune-remote
  scm:
   - git:
     prune: true
```

Full online documentation: https://jenkins-job-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scm.html#scm.git